# Where i have put token in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm developing a Mobile Apps. For now i put my access token on SharedPrefences. I want to ask is store access token on SharedPrefences secure? if no where is best practice to put access token.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You should use EncryptedSharedPreferences instead of SharedPreferences as described in the official documentation https://developer.android.com/topic/security/data#edit-shared-preferences